# How to properly set shared volumes in the docker-compose.yml?

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

## Task:

- Set up jenkins on the AWS server and execute automation tests in job

## Steps:

- I created docker-compose.yml and started on the server:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "22:22"
      - "443:443"

    volumes:
      - jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /home/user/.ssh:/var/jenkins_home/.ssh 
    depends_on:
      - java

  java:
    image: openjdk:17-jdk
    volumes:
      - ./my-java-project:/app
      - jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home <------- updated
    working_dir: /app
    command: tail -f /dev/null

volumes:
  jenkins_data:
```

- I successfully started the jenkins with ec2-ip:8080

## Now we can continue to the gitlab-integration steps:

- So I created and established connection in the job
- added Git as Source Code Management
- after I executed job all looks fine, but the project was successfully downloaded into inner /var/jenkins_home/... folder, and not to the server and I can't use this project in following (from the java docker container)

How to properly set shared volumes in the docker-compose.yml?

---

Additional info: the folder my-java-project is created on the server in the home directory (full path: /home/ec2-user/jenkins/my-java-project) but this folder is empty after job execution

Comment: You did not mount the `jenkins_data` volume within your Java container, therefore the Java container can't access it.

Comment: The full path to the folder is /var/jenkins_home/workspace/NAME_OF_THE_JOB

Comment: Yes. This path is exist in the docker container, and there is exist a my project. But I do not have a such path on the server. I mean the my project

Comment: @Mushroomator I updated the question (.yml file). Are you mean this line? - still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just mount same volume on multiple docker containers and create shared storage.

```
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "22:22"
      - "443:443"

    volumes:
      - jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /home/user/.ssh:/var/jenkins_home/.ssh 
    depends_on:
      - java

  java:
    image: openjdk:17-jdk
    volumes:
      - ./my-java-project:/app
      - jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home  # <------- add this
    working_dir: /app
    command: tail -f /dev/null

volumes:
  jenkins_data:
```

Comment: Unfortunately not helped